# Select rows from table A where string exists in a similar column in table B or table C

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 3 different SQL tables that I am working with. Here is what the table look like:

```
Master Accounts
---------------
CustomerNumber PK
CompanyName
More Columns...

Bill Tos
---------------
MasterCustomerNumber FK
CompanyName

Ship Tos
---------------
MasterCustomerNumber FK
CompanyName
```

I want to write a MS SQL query that returns all the columns in the Master Accounts table where a company name contains the string 'ama' in any of the three tables.

Here is my current SQL:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  MA.*
FROM MasterAccounts MA
LEFT JOIN BillTos BT
  ON MA.CustNo = BT.MasterCustNo
LEFT JOIN ShipTos ST
  ON MA.CustNo = ST.MasterCustNo
WHERE MA.CompanyName LIKE '%ama%' OR BT.CompanyName LIKE '%ama%' OR ST.CompanyName LIKE '%ama%'
```

My goal is to get all master accounts where a billto or a shipto companyname contains 'ama'.

Comment: What is the difficulty you are facing?

Comment: I am querying my database with my current query but it is not bringing back any results which I expected some. I feel like there is something wrong with my joins. Does it look correct?

Comment: Query looks good. Can you share some sample data and the result you are expecting?

Comment: I like to type `LEFT OUTER JOIN` just to be explicit - but your query definitely looks like it should work.  Are you sure you have company names that include 'ama'?

Comment: It could be a conversion issue - what type is [CompanyName]?  Have you tried casting is as a varchar in your `WHERE` clause?

Comment: The query definitely works. I tried it out on a similar schema I had. The only thing I can point at is that BT.MasterCustNo is not equal to Bill Tos.MasterCustomerNumber. Similarly, Ship Tos.MasterCustomerNumber not equal to ST.MasterCustNo. Are you certain that SSMS is not giving you a red squiggly line that points to an error somewhere.

Comment: Actually, I believe that it is working but it is taking 10 minutes plus to run the query...I will try using the LEFT OUTER JOIN to see if it speeds it up. The company name in the master account is varchar(100). In the billto and shipto the column is a varchar(35)

Comment: The LEFT OUTER JOIN sped it up a lot...but still kinda of slow (2 mins). Any other suggestions to speed it up?

Comment: Check the execution plan and look for potential indexes to improve performance.

Comment: I added some new indexes but I believe that the DISTINCT is the issue. Is there a different way of writing this without the DISTINCT keyword because when I remove it the query runs instantly?

Comment: @Aaron Yes, you can group by the columns that you want - instead of using `DISTINCT`, but I don't think that will improve your performance - just mentioning it's another way to get distinct records.

Comment: Distinct sorts the rows in order to find duplicates so it is based on all the rows you are selecting. If you take a step back and think about it... the more columns you have the slower distinct is because of how wide the comparison is. The best method to avoid this is to make the result set distinct in your joins and conditions. What is causing the duplication? It's a join... and it's only a duplicate because you aren't returning a row which makes it unique (usually). See if you can reduce the joining criteria to be more limiting.

Comment: Also, based on your last comment in the post, you can turn this into an INNER JOIN instead of a LEFT JOIN. The WHERE condition is negating the left join anyhow. MA.CompanyName LIKE '%ama% also isn't needed if you only want where a billto or a shipto companyname contains 'ama'. as you stated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I read yours comments and maybe this go faster:

```
select MA.* from
MasterAccounts MA
join 
(select CustNo  nmb from MasterAccounts where CompanyName LIKE '%ama%'
union 
select MasterCustNo nmb from BillTos  where CompanyName LIKE '%ama%'
union 
select MasterCustNo nmb from ShipTos where CompanyName LIKE '%ama%' ) num on (num.nmb = MA.CustNo)
```

if you need more companies maybe you use company name in lower case...

*if is small error in query i'm sorry - i read this fast....